# How do I get rid of the annoying clipboard icon in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, clipboard

The question says it all.  That stupid thing really plays havoc with my efforts when I am dealing with small shapes.  None of the internet answers I have found are applicable, probably because I am working on a Mac.  Running Office 2016, BTW.  Thanks.

Comment: Some screen shots help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: [Turning Off the Clipboard Icon (Microsoft Word)](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013446_Turning_Off_the_Clipboard_Icon.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill  Thank you very much for trying to help.  However, nothing his article shows looks like anything that pops up on my desktop.  I don't know if that is because I am running on a Mac, or because I am trying to work with PowerPoint, not Word.  Thanks just the same.